# Cannot enable folder references in Lotus Notes database

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

in an external program that accesses various lotus database I get the following error:

> Error 4386 occured in line 43: Database does not support folder
>   references

Usually this program is supposed to enable folder references by itself which doesn't seem to work. So I asked their support and they gave me the following script to enable folder references:

```
Dim session As New NotesSession
Dim db As NotesDatabase
Set db = session.CurrentDatabase

If  db.FolderReferencesEnabled  Then
    If Messagebox ("Folder References are enabled." & Chr(10) & Chr(10) _
    & "Do you want to disable the Folder References?" ,1 + 32,db.title) = 1 Then
      db.FolderReferencesEnabled = False
      Messagebox "Disabled Folder References now.....", 64, db.title        
    Else
      Exit Sub      
    End If  
Else
    If Messagebox ("Folder References are disabled." & Chr(10) & Chr(10) _
    & "Do you want to enable the Folder References?" ,1 + 32,db.title) = 1   Then
      db.FolderReferencesEnabled = True
      Messagebox "Enabeled Folder References now.....", 64, db.title
    End If
End If
```

I get an error in the line `db.FolderReferencesEnabled = True` saying the same again:

> Database does not support folder references

Does anyone have an idea on how I can enable folder references for a database?

---

EDIT: The database in question is a replication. I was able to enable folder references in the original database and the folder properties are getting copied.

However, the replica still throws this error that it doesn't support folder references if I try to enable them. Is this an expected behaviour?

Comment: What is the ODS of the databases? If it is VERY old, then this might be the reason... (See link of Knut saying "The database must be at the Release 5 file format level or greater.")

Comment: @TorstenLink ODS Version is 52.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our Notes admin was finally able to fix this problem by simply running `updall`, `compact`, `fixup`. We can't say which of these utilities actually fixed the problem though.

[Administrator Guide for Domino Server maintenance](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27006573)

Comment: Most probably the compact did... I think the ODS of the database was to old, and compact updated the ODS to the right version.

Answer (score 1):

> The database must have the $FolderInfo and $FolderRefInfo hidden views
>   to support folder references. These views can be copied from the mail
>   template.

... according to [documentation](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.1/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_FOLDERREFERENCESENABLED_PROPERTY_4434_ABOUT.html?lang=en).

Another cause might be an insufficient access level in ACL for NotesID which executes the code.

Sometimes views are broken. Delete views $FolderInfo and $FolderRefInfo and copy these views from mail template back again.

Comment: if I hold Ctrl/Shift and choose View -> Go to... I can see $FolderInfo and $FolderRefInfo

Comment: The user has manager rights. I'm now waiting on a call from the vendor's professional support and will post the results

Comment: Try to delete and re-copy views. Sometimes views are broken.

Comment: Thanks for your help so far. I have edited the question. I had to recreate the whole database (replica). FolderRef properties are shown now but the db still won't let me enable folder references.